# check the string conditions and print the required one in file using java

Tags: java, string, file, multiline, csv

In my file some 50 lines of string data is present that is delimited by starting with `1002` and ending with `1003`, for example:

```
1002target data A10034d8e
```

but either or both of the delimiters can be split over multiple lines, for example:

```
10
02target data B1003922510
02target data C10
033d0910
02target data D10033d09
```

How can I print only the delimited data from a file, excluding starting and ending delimiters?

My code is:

```
try {
    File file = new File("new1.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    int lines = 0, b;
    String seq = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines++;
        if (lines == 2) {
            StringBuilder bulid = new StringBuilder(line);

            bulid.delete(0, 2);
            b = bulid.length();
            bulid.delete(b - 8, b);

            stringBuffer.append(bulid);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            lines = 0;
        }
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this code works only when the data and delimiters are on one line.

Answer (score 0):

For each line:

search index of 1002 and if found search index of 1003 print what in the middle.

```
int start = line.indexOf("1002");
if (start >= 0) {
    int end = line.indexOf("1003", start);
    if (end >= 0) {
        String searched = line.substr(start + 4, end);
        // Doing something with searched
    }
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

Comment: This is the code for one line. If you put it in a loop it works for all lines.

Comment: i have one doubt in second line only 10 is present... when apply a loop can it automatically goes to next line checking 02..

Comment: while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
   int start = line.indexOf("1002");
    if (start >= 0) 
    {
      int end = line.indexOf("1003", start);
       if (end >= 0) 
      {
         String searched = line.substring(start + 4, end);
         System.out.println(searched.toString());
                                 // Doing something with searched
        }
                            
      } 
        else 
        {
                              // Not found
        }   
    }      // Is this is correct or not..

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this is that after your bufferedReader reads the line with data 1002 , you have to start performing your operation. and perform it till you get 1003.And if there can be more than one 1002s in a single line then you'll have to check for that as well.So

```
 String data;
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFilePath"));
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(br.readLine());
 while(sb!=null){
 int start = sb.indexOf("1002",0);
 while(start!=-1){
 int end = sb.indexOf("1003",start);
 if(end!=-1)
    data = sb.substring(start,end);
 else
    data = sub.substring(start);
  //do stuff with your data
 ...
 if(end==-1)
  break;
  else 
  start = sb.indexOf("1002",end);
  }
 sb = br.nextLine();
  }
```

Comment: sb=br.nextLine(); //cannot find symbol

Comment: check the scopes of br and sb in your code.Also check your curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

To print all text between `1002` and `1003` found anywhere in a file, can be done in one statement:

```
Arrays.stream(Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/data.txt")).collect(Collectors.joining())
  .replaceAll("^.*?1002|1003(.(?!1002))*$", "") // trim leading/trailing non-data
  .split("1003.*?1002"))                        // split on end-to-start-of-next
.forEach(System.out::println);                  // print each data
```

Comment: @ven are there any lines in your file with 1002, then some text, then 1003, somewhere between in the line

Comment: it is working if whole data is in same line. if 10 is in first line and remaining   data is in second line it does not works.

Comment: output is coming more times i.e., not one time

Comment: @ven yes, it prints every data found in the file. What did you want? The first only? Something else?

Comment: @ven impossible. You must have duplicate data in the file.

Comment: there are no duplicates in my file

Comment: @ven please edit your question to post a section of your file into it, so we see exactly what you're processing and so we can use it for testing. I created a file to this this code and it worked OK..